# Excel: How to Use AVERAGEIFS with Multiple Ranges (different columns)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Date | Group A | Group B | Group C | Group A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sub Group | A1 | B1 | C1 | A2 |
| 1/1/2022 | 35 | 12 | 54 | 10 |
| 1/2/2022 | 43 | 45 | 62 | 93 |
| 1/3/2022 | 76 | 65 | 39 | 48 |
| 1/4/2022 | 12 | 25 | 81 | 18 |
| 1/5/2022 | 89 | 76 | 20 | 26 |
| 1/6/2022 | 23 | 87 | 47 | 17 |
| 1/7/2022 | 56 | 59 | 21 | 53 |
| 1/8/2022 | 29 | 51 | 9 | 68 |
| 1/9/2022 | 76 | 8 | 52 | 35 |
| 1/10/2022 | 36 | 53 | 38 | 53 |

**User Input**
**Start Dt** - `1/1/2022`

**End Dt** - `1/5/2022`

**Group** - `Group B`

**Question**
What is the daily average of a Group given the above user input?

**Formula**
`=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX($B$2:$E$11,,MATCH($I$3,$B$1:$E$1,0)), $A$2:$A$11, ">="&$G$3, $A$2:$A$11, "<="&$H$3)`

**Answer**
`44.6`

User will select a start date, end date and Group.
I want to compute the daily average of that.
The issue arises when there are multiple columns with same group as Averageif takes the first column only.

**Issue - How can I find the daily average of Group A for the given dates, given that Group A are in two columns (they can't be combined as there are multiple sub groups)**

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then can try-

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(FILTER(B3:E12,B1:E1=I2),(A3:A12>=H1)*(A3:A12<=H2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution. I believe you could avoid nesting filters by multiplying all of the criteria inside the first filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older version you could use:

```
=AVERAGE(
         INDEX(A1:E12, 
         AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A3:A12)/(A3:A12>=G3)/(A3:A12<=H3),   
                   ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT((A3:A12>=G3)*(A3:A12<=H3))))), 
         AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(B1:E1)/(B1:E1=I3), 
                   TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,SUMPRODUCT(N(B1:E1=I3))))))))
```

Entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` (I think)

In the picture below `J3` shows the answer cell. `K3` is used to demonstrate the array that is used for the `AVERAGE` function (a Office 365 spill range).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another old school approach. User input fields in the formula are referenced using named ranges.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$12>=StartDt)*($A$3:$A$12<=EndDt)
*($B1:$E$1=Group)*($B$3:$E$12))/(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$12,">="&StartDt,$A$3:$A$12,"<="&EndDt)
*(COUNTIF($B$1:$E$1,Group)))
```

[image]